# What is the backup cycle of BlueMix platform and who to contact if data recovery is needed?

Tags: backup, ibm-cloud, cloudant, dashdb

Our client running their apps in bluemix public platform. They need to know when do the backup cycle happens in bluemix. Also in case something happened and they need to recover who they need to contact to?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to IBM's BlueMix support

Comment: Delete the question and contact the IBM Bluemix support. You are also asking for the platform itself and some database services which may have different terms.

Comment: Questions about the Bluemix platform can be asked at https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html. You can contact Bluemix Support at
https://support.ng.bluemix.net/technicalsupport/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I'll contact bluemix support for this info